# Using .NET MVC/WebAPI, Is it possible to share an auth cookie between two projects of the same solution? If so, how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

My solution is structured like this:

- Web Project (Default, ASP.NET MVC)
- API Project (ASP.NET MVC using WebAPI controllers)

When deployed to a server, the web project will be the root and the api project will live in `root\api`.

I am authenticating users in the web app using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("foo",false);` and so of course within a controller of the **web project** I have no problem reading the cookie back (`HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`).

I would like to be able to do the same in my API project when an `ajax` request is made from a page in the web project so that I can check that the user is authenticated before remitting a service.

Is this possible?

## Update

I followed [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for creating authentication across applications, and I still can not read my auth cookie in the API context.  I am wondering if it is because I am running in local host while the `Forms` node in the web configs expect a domain name:

```
 <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
        protection="All"  
        path="/" 
        domain="contoso.com" 
        timeout="30" />
```

I tried setting the domain to `localhost:XXXX` but that didn't work either.  The machine keys in both applications match.

Comment: As far as im aware, both domains need to be the same. If you're running one project locally you can point 127.0.0.1 to the right domain via your host file. If you required shared auth across different domains you will need to look at a single sign on solution.

Comment: Basically a cookie will not transfer between domains so you need to make them the same.